# How to use Spring kafka transactions with Spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

How to use Spring kafka transaction with Spring data jpa transaction? The jpa transaction manager in my application is disappeared and throw this error: `A component required a bean named 'transactionManager' that could not be found.` Even if I create a JPA transaction manager bean, the transaction method seems to only use one of two transaction managers `JpaTransactionManager` or `KafkaTransactionManager` so it only rollback kafka or jpa not both. After that I have tried implemented like this example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/tips.html#ex-jdbc-sync but it still not working and throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6baee63b] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread`. Could anyone please help me with this?

Here is the code that I have implemented:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        factory.setTransactionIdPrefix("tx-");
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory); 
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager(ProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<Integer, String>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

My producer method:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ProducerTest {
    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            kafkaTemplate.send("test", Integer.toString(i)); // Not rolled back
            countryRepository.save(Country.builder().name("test").id(i).build()); // Rolled back successfully.If I comment this line, Spring will use kafkaTransactionManager bean.

            if (i > 3) {
                throw new RuntimeException("TEST ROLLBACK");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My spring-boot version is 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of trying to find a solution to my problem, I came up with this workaround. I divided my method into two separate transactions and called them one after the other.

```java
@Service
public class TransactionCallService {
    @Transactional(value = "kafkaTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    public <T> T runInNewTransaction(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ProducerTest {
    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;
    private TransactionCallService transactionCallService;

    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            countryRepository.save(Country.builder()
                    .name(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 5)).id(i).build());
        }
        transactionCallService.runInNewTransaction(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                kafkaTemplate.send("test", Integer.toString(i));
            }
            int c = 1 / 0; // produce a error to test rollback
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

However, This is the only approach that works for me. I would be grateful if someone could offer a better or different way to solve this issue.